# Is it feasible to implement a functional smart contract language for Ethereum?

Tags: dapp-development

Would it be feasible to implement Clojure (and persistent data structures) on EVM?
Or another functional language?

Comment: to do so you need to code your own compiler or rewrite the VM

Comment: Why would you have to rewrite the vm? Thats not true, as all functional languages run on normal vms and normal cpus alike.

Comment: Ethereum VM is special read the yellow paper

Comment: As long as you wrote a compiler that created byte code that the existing VM could understand, you wouldn't need to create a new EVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you'd need to create your compiler to generate EVM bytecode. There are alternatives to solidity, they are LLL (which is functional and Lisp like) 
https://github.com/nexusdev/lll-resurrected

and Serpent which looks more like a Python.
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent

Assumed you generate a proper bytecode and an ABI, I guess you can use almost any language to write contracts.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html