# Are there any functional programming languages for Ethereum smart contracts?

Tags: contract-development, evm

Are there any functional programming languages for Ethereum smart contracts in development or production?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a functional language for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/is-there-a-functional-language-for-ethereum)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I think this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/is-there-a-functional-language-for-ethereum title should be changed to "Is it feasible to implement a functional language for Ethereum?" because the content of that question and the answers are about feasibility. My question is about the existence of such languages in development or production.

Comment: Hmm, I'm inclined to agree with you. The accepted answer kind of answers both questions though, which blurs it even more. However, I've gone ahead and edited the title of the other question, and retracted my close vote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately now there is nothing really suitable, but you can see here starts in Lisp and Haskell: https://github.com/pirapira/fp-ethereum 
They pursue the same goals.

Comment: Also there is https://github.com/raineorshine/functional-solidity-language but seems pretty quite